# Encrypt and protect file with python

Tags: python, encryption, cryptography, pycrypto

I want to create a file in a python3 program, in which I want to store some information that I don't want users to see or manipulate. However, in execution time I need to read and modify its content, being sure that users cannot modify the content of the file. How can I achive this?

Answer (score 2):

All information stored on end-user devices can eventually be manipulated.
One option is storing the data you don't want users to manipulate on a web-server and retrieve/update it when needed.
The downside of this approach is that your code cannot work offline.

Comment: Do you have a reference where I can find how to do this? Is possible to save information locally and send it when conection is available?

Comment: "_All information stored on end-user devices can eventually be manipulated_", so no, I don't have any suggestion to do so.

Comment: I mean, where can I find how do I send it to a web-server and retrieve when needed

Comment: Use [requests](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/) or [socket](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html) modules.

Answer (score 0):

In this example I used Fernet and a key created with a password "hardcode".
You can encrypt the file and decrypt the information inside only when they are necessary.
If you have to modify the information, you can just call again the encrypt function.

```
from cryptography.fernet import Fernet
import base64, hashlib


def encrypt(filename, key):
    f = Fernet(key)
    with open(filename, "rb") as file:
        # read the encrypted data
        file_data = file.read()
    # encrypt data
    encrypted_data = f.encrypt(file_data)
    # write the encrypted file
    with open(filename, "wb") as file:
        file.write(encrypted_data)
    
    
def decrypt(filename, key):
    f = Fernet(key)
    with open(filename, "rb") as file:
        # read the encrypted data
        encrypted_data = file.read()
    # decrypt data
    decrypted_data = f.decrypt(encrypted_data)
    print(decrypted_data)

my_password = 'mypassword'.encode()
key = hashlib.md5(my_password).hexdigest()
key_64 = base64.urlsafe_b64encode(key.encode("utf-8"))

# file name
file = "test.txt"
# encrypt it
encrypt(file, key_64)
with open("test.txt", "rb") as f:
    print(f.read())
decrypt(file, key_64)
```

Comment: Do you plan to hardcode the password or key? If that's the case, this is definitely **not** the way to go.

Comment: @PedroLobito that was just an example about how Fernet works. Of course it is possible to create a better key and not use an hardcoded password.

Comment: @PedroLobito however, there are cases where you can use a "web-server and retrieve/update it when needed" like in ChatoPaka's answer, and cases where you cannot use that solution. In my case, customer uses my software in very large productions, where there are lots of operators that can touch my configurations files. It is impossible to say "don't touch those files", because 100% someone will touch them. In those cases I suppose that a "stupid" encrypt protection could be enough to stop this problem.

Comment: Not sure to understand: in this example the software don"t need to hardcode the password "my_password", it is the operator that needs to store it? Or I don't understand?

Comment: When you used: "key = hashlib.md5(encoded_Pwd).hexdigest()" is it the creation of a public key from the private key "encoded_Pw"?

Answer (score 0):

You may store the private information in a python object, e.g. dictionary, etc. and then compile it (*.py-->*.pyc), encrypt the source file (*.py-->*.py.cpt) and finally publish only the compiled file, optionally with its encrypted pair (while keeping the encryption key safely to yourself).

You may find additional details [here](https://sgino209.medium.com/python-with-hidden-sources-a09e52fc0f0c).